# MySqlCommand in Asp.net WEB Forms to Display in Label

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

i have this sql command

```
string myreg = "select registration_no from truck where truck_id ='" + truckID + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myreg, conn);
```

i want to put the value of `myreg` to my `RegistrationNo.Text` label.

i have this  `RegistrationNo.Text = myreg;` and it displays select registration_no from truck where truck_id on my page

Answer (score 1):

You need to read something about the workings of [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx) and its providers.
To get the result of that query in your textbox you need

- Open a connection to your MySql Server
- Prepare a command to send to the Server
- Get back the result
- Write the result to your textbox

All these passages requires the use of specific classes and some code to glue everything together

```
 // Prepare your command using a parameter placeholder
 string myreg = "select registration_no from truck where truck_id =@id";

 // Build the connection to the server and build the command to execute
 using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(.... the connection string that identifies your server and db ))
 using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myreg, cnn))
 {
      // Open the connection
      cnn.Open();

      // Add the parameter expected 
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = truckID;

      // Execute the command and get back the return value (if found)
      object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

      // Check if the ExecuteScalar has returned something
      if(result != null)
           RegistrationNo.Text = result.ToString();
      else
           ... message to your user about the failed search ...
 }
```

PS. I have assumed that your variable truckID is a string because in your original code you have passed it between single quotes, but if it is an integer then you need to modify the parameter type to MySqlDbType.Int32
Also, I have used the [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx) because I think that your query returns just a row with a single column and for this task it is better to use ExecuteScalar

Answer (score 0):

You can use datareader also.See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

```
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
     "SQL Query",
      connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                reader.GetString(1));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```